# $(document).ready() event not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb, jquery-ui-accordion, document-ready

I have jQuery loading correctly on Rails 3, and the `$(document).ready()` event never gets run. I know this because I tried running the code within the `$(document).ready();` manually via Google Chrome's Javascript Console and it ran just fine.

I'm not sure at all what's wrong, so I thought I'd ask StackOverFlow

Please note that the ERB/HTML isn't of good quality yet. I'm just learning this.

Here's the ERB:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #Agenda
            {
                background-color: #36175E;
                width: 960px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #assignment
            {
                background: green;
                width: 600px;
                height: 500px;
                float: right;
                margin: auto;

            }
            #accordion
            {
                margin: auto;
                width: 350px;
                height: 500px;
                float: left;
            }


        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#accordion').accordion();
                SetupAccordionItems();
                });


            //This is probably not the best way to do it
            $('li[id]').click(function(e)
            {
                SetupAssignment(this.id);
            });

            function SetupAssignment(Assignment_ID) 
            {
                if (Assignment_ID != null)
                {
                    $('#ShowAssignmentInstructions').fadeOut('slow');
                    document.getElementbyID(ShowAssignmentInstructions).visibility = "hidden";
                    var Assignment = "BAEGLS";
                    document.getElementbyID(Assignment_Name).InnerText = Assignment.name;
                    document.getElementbyID(Due_Date).InnerText = Assignment.due_date;
                    if (Assignment.image == null)
                    {
                        Assignment.image = Assignment.Unit.Image;
                    }
                    document.getElementbyID(Assignment_Image).src = Assignment.Image;
                    //Resets contents of the paragraph describing the assignment
                    document.getElementByID(basic_assignment_info).InnerText = null;
                    document.getElementbyID(basic_assignment_info).InnerText = "This assignment is worth " + Assignment.DefaultMaximumPoints + "points.";
                    document.getElementbyID(assignment).style.visibility = "visibility";
                    document.getElementbyID(Assignment_Status).src = Assignment.Status;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#ShowAssignmentInstructions').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }
            function SetupAccordionItems()
            {
                var AssignmentsDueNextSchoolDay = <%= GetByDueDateForCurrentUser(@nextSchoolDay) %>;
                var AssignmentsDueNextNextSchoolDay = <%= GetByDueDateForCurrentUser(@nextNextSchoolDay) %>;
                var AssignmentsDueNextNextNextSchoolDay = <%= GetByDueDateForCurrentUser(@nextNextNextSchoolDay) %>;

                for (assignment in AssignmensDueNextSchoolDay)
                {
                    AppendAccordionItem(Assignment, "DueInOneSchoolDay");
                }
                for (Assignment in AssignmentsDueNextNextSchoolDay)
                {
                    AppendAccordionItem(Assignment, "DueInTwoSchoolDays");
                }
                for (Assignment in AssignmentsDueNextNextNextSchoolDay)
                {
                    AppendAccordionItem(Assignment, "DueInThreeSchoolDays");
                }

            }
            function AppendAccordionItem(Item, ID)
            {
                $("<li>", {id:Item.ID, text:Item.Name}).appendTo(ID);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="Agenda">
            <h1 id="Agenda_Title">Agenda</h1>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion">

                <h3 id="TomorrowsDate"><%= @nextSchoolDay %></h3>
                <ul id="DueInOneSchoolDay">

                        </ul>
                    <h3 id="DueDayAfterTomorrow_Title"><%= @nextNextSchoolDay %></h3>
                    <div>
                        <ul id="DueInTwoSchoolDays">
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h3 id="DueDayAfterDayAfterTomorrrow_Title"><%= @nextNextNextSchoolDay %></h3>
                     <ul id="DueInThreeSchoolDays">
                         </ul>


            </div>
            <div id="assignment" display="hidden">
                <h2 id="Assignment_Name"><center>Assignment Name</center></h2>
                <h3 id="Due_Date"><center>Due Date</center></h3>
                <img id="Assignment_Image" src="#"/>
                <br>
                <button id="Start_Assignment">Start Assignment</button>
                <p id="basic_assignment_info">
                </p>
                <img id="Assignment_Status" src="#"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the HTML outputted by the ERB

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #Agenda
            {
                background-color: #36175E;
                width: 960px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            #assignment
            {
                background: green;
                width: 600px;
                height: 500px;
                float: right;
                margin: auto;

            }
            #accordion
            {
                margin: auto;
                width: 350px;
                height: 500px;
                float: left;
            }


        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#accordion').accordion();
                SetupAccordionItems();
                });


            //This is probably not the best way to do it
            $('li[id]').click(function(e)
            {
                SetupAssignment(this.id);
            });

            function SetupAssignment(Assignment_ID) 
            {
                if (Assignment_ID != null)
                {
                    $('#ShowAssignmentInstructions').fadeOut('slow');
                    document.getElementbyID(ShowAssignmentInstructions).visibility = "hidden";
                    var Assignment = "BAEGLS";
                    document.getElementbyID(Assignment_Name).InnerText = Assignment.name;
                    document.getElementbyID(Due_Date).InnerText = Assignment.due_date;
                    if (Assignment.image == null)
                    {
                        Assignment.image = Assignment.Unit.Image;
                    }
                    document.getElementbyID(Assignment_Image).src = Assignment.Image;
                    //Resets contents of the paragraph describing the assignment
                    document.getElementByID(basic_assignment_info).InnerText = null;
                    document.getElementbyID(basic_assignment_info).InnerText = "This assignment is worth " + Assignment.DefaultMaximumPoints + "points.";
                    document.getElementbyID(assignment).style.visibility = "visibility";
                    document.getElementbyID(Assignment_Status).src = Assignment.Status;
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#ShowAssignmentInstructions').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            }
            function SetupAccordionItems()
            {
                var AssignmentsDueNextSchoolDay = <%= GetByDueDateForCurrentUser(@nextSchoolDay) %>;
                var AssignmentsDueNextNextSchoolDay = <%= GetByDueDateForCurrentUser(@nextNextSchoolDay) %>;
                var AssignmentsDueNextNextNextSchoolDay = <%= GetByDueDateForCurrentUser(@nextNextNextSchoolDay) %>;

                for (assignment in AssignmensDueNextSchoolDay)
                {
                    AppendAccordionItem(Assignment, "DueInOneSchoolDay");
                }
                for (Assignment in AssignmentsDueNextNextSchoolDay)
                {
                    AppendAccordionItem(Assignment, "DueInTwoSchoolDays");
                }
                for (Assignment in AssignmentsDueNextNextNextSchoolDay)
                {
                    AppendAccordionItem(Assignment, "DueInThreeSchoolDays");
                }

            }
            function AppendAccordionItem(Item, ID)
            {
                $("<li>", {id:Item.ID, text:Item.Name}).appendTo(ID);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>


        <div id="Agenda">
            <h1 id="Agenda_Title">Agenda</h1>
            <div class="accordion" id="accordion">

                <h3 id="TomorrowsDate"><%= @nextSchoolDay %></h3>
                <ul id="DueInOneSchoolDay">

                        </ul>
                    <h3 id="DueDayAfterTomorrow_Title"><%= @nextNextSchoolDay %></h3>
                    <div>
                        <ul id="DueInTwoSchoolDays">
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                    <h3 id="DueDayAfterDayAfterTomorrrow_Title"><%= @nextNextNextSchoolDay %></h3>
                     <ul id="DueInThreeSchoolDays">
                         </ul>


            </div>
            <div id="assignment" display="hidden">
                <h2 id="Assignment_Name"><center>Assignment Name</center></h2>
                <h3 id="Due_Date"><center>Due Date</center></h3>
                <img id="Assignment_Image" src="#"/>
                <br>
                <button id="Start_Assignment">Start Assignment</button>
                <p id="basic_assignment_info">
                </p>
                <img id="Assignment_Status" src="#"/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you importing jQuery?

Comment: Based on your resulting HTML, it looks like it's not even using your `application.html.erb`. Also, if you have an application layout, why are you redeclaring `<html>`, `<head>`, etc. in your view?

Comment: When you say "here's the ERB", where exactly is that file located in your app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to import jquery file like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's done in the application.html.erb file, it automatically imports jQuery to all views.

Comment: (It also wouldn't have worked by putting in the command via the Javascript Console)

Comment: @Indebi: first test that your `$(document).ready()` is working by just putting `alert` in it. Remove rest code and make it sure `$(document).ready()` is working or not.

Comment: jQuery isn't being imported properly then. You also need to move `$('li[id]').click(function(e)` into `$(document).ready`

Comment: @Indebi: That indicate that `JQuery` is not loading correctly.

Comment: The link to jquery must actually be in the html document. If you don't see it in the source page, it's not there, so it's NOT being imported. Since library is not loaded, jquery code will not run.